# Distributing to Specific Screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I have read the Documentation for [distribution to Specfic screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html).

But I have doubt that on, Normal Screen- hdpi itself, we have 3 Screen sizes. that are

- WVGA800 (480x800)
- WVGA854 (480x854)
- 600x1024

For these screen how can distribute my App. My App is collapsing in the screen Samsung Galaxy Tab(600X1024). ANy Idea to handle this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

The link that you give provides information on how you can limit which devices your app will be available to when you publish it to the Android Market.

To actually get your app to display well across different screen sizes and densities is a completely different matter. You should refer to the link that Pragna gave in his answer; you should avoid AbsoluteLayout; you should avoid absolute dimensions and always use dp / sp; you should allow Android to organise your layouts through LinearLayout and RelativeLayout; you should provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities; you should consider optimising your layouts at different screen sizes / densities.

Without seeing any of your code, it is difficult to identify any specific reasons why your app is not working well on the Galaxy Tab, but these are generally the practices that you need to adopt in order to get your app workig across a variety of scree sizes, densities, & form-factors.

Comment: To distribute your app to devices of specific dimensions, ensure that you include the correct compatible-screens in your manifest. That alone will not ensure that it actually *displays* well on those devices, as per my answer.